# Cant add Account on phpMyAdmin/No privileges to administrate user

Tags: sql, phpmyadmin, mariadb, backend

How can I add a user, I cannot even edit the privileges of the other users [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XFmJr.png)
i can find similar questions asked but those answers cant solve my problem

Comment: What command(s) were used to attempt changes?

Comment: Also, what have you tried from the other questions that hasn't worked?